# How to configure gRPC Client communicating over TLS transport layer without server certificate?

Tags: ssl, grpc

Currently I want to expose a gRPC Method as Public API and protected by Auth0 (JWT Token), with Istio(Envoy Proxy) will help validating the token on server side. Since the JWT Token is not encrypted by the standard (it is only used to end-user authentication and authorization layer), I want to encrypt the communication using TLS. Also, my public server already have valid certificate.

The problem is on the gRPC Client side. Every example I look, the gRPC Client have to initialize the TLS Connection with server cert pem file. Is it really necessary? Because it adds operational burden and complexity, where we have to distribute our server pem file everytime we renew the certificate AND/OR the client side has to restart the application.

Thanks,
Agung

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a self signed certificate, then yes you must explicitly trust it in your client.   If you use a publicly signed certificate on your Server, gRPC will use the Operating System's certificate authorities to verify the cert.   (In the case of Java, it uses the JVMs cert authorities.)

Comment: How to setup gRPC to use OS's certificate authorities? Appreciate it if you have some code snippet?

Comment: It does so automatically.  There isn't anything you do to enable it.

Comment: but is there any **online examples** to demonstrate the syntax if use a publicly signed certificate?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a self-signed certificate you need to specify the server's root certificates in the `pem_root_certs` member of the `SslCredentialsOptions` struct passed in when creating a channel, as Carl says.

However if you are using a CA issued certificate, leaving the `pem_root_certs` member empty will cause [gRPC to default to its own master list](https://grpc.io/grpc/cpp/structgrpc_1_1_ssl_credentials_options.html#a01015d8ec7dbf49f2ac3cd21f21d383b) ([reviewable online](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/etc/roots.pem)), [not any OS-specific list](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8393#issuecomment-260812034).

Comment: the first link is dead.